# Bernoulli equation and contact angle: Slip or permeable boundary?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, bernoulli-equation, navier-stokes

It is a simple question related to Bernoulli equations and permeable boundary.
Let $u$ be the velocity potential associated to the velocity fluid $V=\nabla u$ and suppose that the fluid is incompressible
$$
\Delta u=0\quad\mbox{in }D\cap (u>0).
$$
On the other hand, if $p$ is the pression, by the Bernoulli law we have
$$
\nabla\Big(\frac12 |\nabla u|^2 + p\Big)\cdot \nabla u=0
$$
along streamline. Therefore, the system can be formulated as
$$
\Delta u=0\quad\mbox{in }D\cap (u>0),\qquad |\nabla u|=1 \quad\mbox{on }D\cap \partial(u>0)
$$
where $\partial(u>0)$ is the boundary of $(u>0)$. Now, suppose that the free interface $\partial(u>0)$ touches the fixed boundary $\partial D$ in such a way that
$$
\partial_n u = \alpha \quad\mbox{in }\partial D \cap (u>0)
$$
for some $\alpha$ (no sign assumptions) and with $n$ the normal vector to $\partial D$ (I am thinking about a $D=$infinite tube). The problem is that I cannot find reference in which such case as been considered either from a numerical or theoretical point of view: I suspect that this condition give rises to contact angle of the streamline $\partial(u>0)$ with the fixed boundary $\partial D$. Nevertheless, I don't get if this is the "slip-condition" or "permeable-condition".

Unfortunately I don't have a solid physical background, so any advice could be very useful!